# Why converting from base 10 to base 2 is considered slow?

Tags: algorithm

As stated [here](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/22712) it is quadratic, but why?

Comment: Oops, you are right :-(
Should I delete this?

Comment: I don't think you can delete questions with an accepted answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the quadratic part is reading the integer from text. The standard algorithm looks like this:

```
v = 0
for each digit:
    v = v * 10 + digit
```

It looks like this is just O(n) on the number of digits, but if you are working with arbitrary precision integers like this problem then the multiplication by 10 is also O(n), making the whole thing O(n^2).